# input type="file" locks file for ADODB.Recordset

Tags: vbscript, hta

I'm having an use where the `<input type="file">` is locking the file for the ADODB.recordset.

If I hardcode the filepath the code runs without an issue however as soon as I browse using input type of file and select the hardcoded file it locks the file and I can no longer access it via the recordset.

I've tried just around everything I can think of without any success. I know its a result of the input browse function because if I select another file within the same directory or click the process button without browsing the code runs as it should.

Below is the relevant html and vbscript. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Employee Upload</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="Employee Upload"
  ID="Employee Upload"
  VERSION="1.0"/> 

</head>

<body bgcolor="white">
<p id="heading" name="heading"><p>
<div id="container" name="container">
<span onClick="document.getElementById('myFile').click();" language="javascript" class="upload">
<button>Browse</button>
<input id="filename" type="text" disabled value="">
<input type="file" id="myFile" style="visibility:hidden;display:none;" onchange="document.getElementById('filename').value = this.value;document.getElementById('process').style.visibility = 'visible';" language="javascript">
</span>

<p>Click "Process File" once you have selected the file to upload the new hire data.</p>

<button id="process" name="process" onclick="loadFile()" style="/*visibility: hidden;*/">Process File</button>
</div>
<script language="vbscript">

Function loadFile()
On Error Resume Next
fileStr = document.all("filename").value
fileStr = "C:\Users\SeanW\Desktop\imports\NewHires.txt"
fileDir = Left(fileStr,InStrRev(fileStr,"\"))
filenameStr = Right(fileStr,Len(fileStr)-InStrRev(fileStr,"\"))

Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set oRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
oConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
          "Data Source=" & fileDir & ";" & _
          "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""

oRS.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & filenameStr & "]", oConn, 3, 3, 1

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
MsgBox "Error Loading File: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description,vbCritical,"File Load Error"
oConn.Close
oRS.Close
Set oConn = Nothing
Set oRs = Nothing
Err.Clear
Exit Function
else

Msgbox "File Loaded Successfully"
oConn.Close
oRS.Close
Set oConn = Nothing
Set oRs = Nothing

End If

End Function

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly this problem today. I got around it by making a copy of the input file in a subfolder, then connecting to that with the `ADODB.Connection`

```
dim txtfile: txtfile = document.getElementById("filename").Value
dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim tablename: tablename = fso.GetFileName(txtfile)
' we'll create the folder as a subfolder to the current one
dim currentfolder: currentfolder = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")

' create new paths until we have a new one
dim newpath: newpath = fso.BuildPath(currentfolder, fso.GetTempName())
do while fso.folderExists(newpath)
    newpath = fso.BuildPath(currentfolder, fso.GetTempName())
loop

' create the folder & copy the input file
fso.createFolder newpath
fso.copyfile txtfile, fso.buildpath(newpath, tablename)

'connect and process
ado.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
      "Data Source=" & newpath & ";" & _
      "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""

ado.open

'... etc

' clear up the temp folder
fso.deleteFolder newpath, true
```

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37583532/using-file-input-element-in-hta-file-prevents-deleting-selected-file