# Using file input element in hta file prevents deleting selected file

Tags: vbscript, delete-file, hta, html-input

If an input html element of type=file is used to select a file then that file cannot be deleted by the hta program.

This MVCE works but doesn't use the file dialog - you have to type the filename in manually:

```html
<html>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT Language="VBScript">
Sub Process
    Set x = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    MsgBox "this will actually delete "& INIFile.Value
    x.DeleteFile INIFile.Value
    MsgBox "see? "& INIFile.Value &" is gone"
    Set x = Nothing
End Sub
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<body id='body'>
<input type="text" name="INIFile" >
<input type="button" value="Go!" onClick="Process" >
</body>
</html>
```

But this MVCE doesn't work - the file is not deleted; just deferred until the program exits:

```html
<html>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT Language="VBScript">
Sub Process
    Set x = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    MsgBox "try to manually delete "& INIFile.Value &" (and then undo it)"
    x.DeleteFile INIFile.Value
    MsgBox "now try to delete file "& INIFile.Value &" (now it can't be deleted until the app is closed)"
    Set x = Nothing
End Sub
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<body id='body'>
<input type="file" name="INIFile" >
<input type="button" value="Go!" onClick="Process" >
</body>
</html>
```

Somehow using a file type input html element makes it so that the file CAN be manually deleted from outside the program UNTIL the DeleteFile function is called.  The DeleteFile function doesn't actually delete the file - it just deferrs the deletion until the hta program exits - at which point the file finally deletes itself.

I need to delete the file while the program is still running.  Is there any way to use a file type input html element in an hta file and still delete the file while the hta program is running?

**EDIT**

My actual use case!  In an attempt to produce a usable MVCE I didn't realize a solution would be found that doesn't work with my particular requirements.

The reason I am deleting the file is so that I can replace it with something else, so I need the file to disappear before the end of the function.  `Call window.location.reload()` absolutely works but the file disappears at the end of the function.

What I am actually trying to do is something like this:

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT Language="VBScript">
Sub Process
    Dim file: file = INIFile.Value
    Call window.location.reload()

    'backup the file to tempfile.tmp
    'Now edit tempfile.tmp with all the changes and preview it
    'then ask the user whether they are happy with the changes
    'delete the original file
    'and put the tempfile.tmp in its place

    Dim x: Set x = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    x.CopyFile file,"tempfile.tmp"
    x.DeleteFile file
    MsgBox "why is "& file &" still there?"
    x.MoveFile "tempfile.tmp",file ' this produces "file already exists"
    Set x = Nothing
End Sub
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY id='body'>
<INPUT type="file" name="INIFile" onChange="Process">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: What happens if you set the `INIFile.Value` to a variable then set `INIFile.Value` to `""` before calling `x.DeleteFile`? The file input HTML element is designed for uploading files via a form, it makes sense that it stores a handle to the file. Interesting to know if it carries on holding it if you set the `value` attribute to empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regular text input box

```
<input type="text" name="FileName" size="30">
```

Add a button to click to open the file

```
<input type="button" onClick="SelectFile" value="Browse...">
```

Add a file dialog object

```
<OBJECT id=Dlg classid="CLSID:3050F4E1-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B" width=0 height=0>
```

Add a sub to take the return value of this object and put it in your text box.

```
Sub SelectFile
    FileName.value = ""
    strStartPath = "C:\Test"
    strFilter = "Text (*.txt;*.csv)| *.txt;*.csv|VBScript (*.vbs;*.vbc)|*.vbs;*.vbc|HTML (*.htm;*.html;*.hta)|*.htm;*.html;*.hta|All Files (*.*)|*.*|"
    strCaption = "Select a File"
    FileName.value = Dlg.openfiledlg(CStr(strStartPath), , CStr(strFilter), CStr(strCaption))
End Sub
```

The strStartPath, strFilter, and strCaption variables can be excluded or customized as needed.

FileName.value will contain the path to the file and it will not be locked.

Edit:
Here's the entire HTA, excluding code to delete the file (I *have* tested this with the delete code):

```
<html>
<HEAD>
<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="Select File"
  ID="SelectFileApplication"
  VERSION="1.0"/>
<SCRIPT Language="VBScript">

Sub SelectFile
    FileName.value = ""
    strStartPath = "C:\Test"
    strFilter = "Text (*.txt;*.csv)| *.txt;*.csv|VBScript (*.vbs;*.vbc)|*.vbs;*.vbc|HTML (*.htm;*.html;*.hta)|*.htm;*.html;*.hta|All Files (*.*)|*.*|"
    strCaption = "Select a File"
    FileName.value = Dlg.openfiledlg(CStr(strStartPath), , CStr(strFilter), CStr(strCaption))
    'The file at FileName.value can be deleted at this point.
End Sub

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<body id="body">
<input type="text" name="FileName" size="30">
<input type="button" onClick="SelectFile" value="Browse...">
<OBJECT id=Dlg classid="CLSID:3050F4E1-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B" width=0 height=0>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: An important bit is that the object tag must be the last thing in the body - if you put it further up for some reason the rest of the page doesn't render.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** *Based on [feedback from OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37583532/using-file-input-element-in-hta-file-prevents-deleting-selected-file#comment62664441_37586533)*

Well have now tested this approach myself with similar results to the OP so thought I'd investigate further.

The File Handle appears to be held for the life of the page, tried the following

- Encapsulating in a `<form>` then calling `Reset()` method
- Clearing the `<input>` `value` attribute and using a variable to hold the file path.

Neither work but while tested realised that if you refresh the page inside the HTA the file deletion occurs, this means that forcing the page to reload should work, so ended up doing just that.

```html
<html>
<HEAD>
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="oHTA"
     APPLICATIONNAME="myApp"
     BORDER="thin"
     BORDERSTYLE="normal"
     CAPTION="yes"
     ICON=""
     MAXIMIZEBUTTON="yes"
     MINIMIZEBUTTON="yes"
     SHOWINTASKBAR="no"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="no"
     SYSMENU="yes"
     VERSION="1.0"
     WINDOWSTATE="normal"/>
<SCRIPT Language="VBScript">
```

```vb
Sub Process
    Set x = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    MsgBox "try to manually delete "& INIFile.Value &" (and then undo it)"
    x.DeleteFile INIFile.Value
    'Reload page
    Call window.location.reload()
End Sub
```

```html
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<body id='body'>
<input type="file" name="INIFile" >
<input type="button" value="Go!" onClick="Process" >
</body>
</html>
```

which works, obviously this isn't ideal for capturing the fact the file has been deleted as the page is reloaded but the OP hasn't gone into detail as to their requirement.

You could also make the the `Go` button a `<input type="submit">` and use the `OnSubmit` event to call `Process()` which might be cleaner approach then calling `window.location.reload()`.

**Further Update:**

From testing with multiple files have noticed that once another file is selected using the `<input type="file">` the previous file is deleted as the handle is released and given to the newly selected file.

I wonder if cloning the `<input type="file">` element and removing the previous one will have the same effect and avoid needing to reload the page?

---

> **Update:** *Have since tested and does still hold on to the File Handle*

The `<input type="file">` is designed for uploading files so it makes sense that once you have selected a file the HTA holds a handle open to it. That being said, there is no reason why you have to call the value of `INIFile` directly instead store it in a variable *(after all it's just a string)* and then clear the `Value` attribute of the `<input>`.

```vb
Sub Process
    Dim x: Set x = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Get file path from INPUT
    Dim file: file = INIFile.Value
    'Reset file INPUT
    INIFile.Value = ""
    MsgBox "this will actually delete "& file
    x.DeleteFile file
    MsgBox "see? "& file &" is gone"
    Set x = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [How do you set file input to nothing with JavaScript or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1342039/692942)

Comment: I am sure I tried this (and many many other things) before I posted and I have just tried it again just now - it does the same thing (locks the file and doesn't delete it until the program ends)  Does it work for you?  I wonder what I am doing wrong...

Comment: @JerryJeremiah How about debugging it, add a line to check whether `INIFile.Value` is empty, it might be the HTA is blocking access to the `Value` so it's never getting unset. Have you tried adding a `<form>` and using the `Reset()` method to blank the `<input>`?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah You are also treating it as a standard HTML page, where is the [`<HTA:APPLICATION />`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536495(v=vs.85).aspx) tag?, without it you won't have access to certain features that are protected in standard HTML in the Browser.

Comment: I left everything unnecessary out of the MVCE. It doesn't work either way. - removing the HTA tag did not change anything so I left it out.  You were right about writing to the INIFile.value - it doesn't do anything.  But the form reset() function does clear it - unfortunately it doesn't prevent the script from locking the file instead of deleting it.  I will update the question with my current test MVCE.

Comment: I really wish we could make this work somehow.  Thanks for all the suggestions.